# How to setup TFS2010 to use Jenkins build server

Tags: tfs, hudson, jenkins

We use Jenkins as our CI build server but have moved over to TFS to do all the project management stuff (user stories, dev tasks, test cases, reporting, automation).  How do I setup TFS2010 to use our Jenkins build server?

Answer (score 6):

it's actually more like the other way around.  You need to configure the TFS plugin for Jenkins, telling it to use TFS as your source control system.  below is a link to the jenkins TFS plug-in...

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Team+Foundation+Server+Plugin