# Can I make Microsoft Team Foundation Server use Subversion and Jenkins?

Tags: svn, tfs, jenkins

(I have attempted to do my homework, but haven't really found an answer to this question.)

Is there a way to make Microsoft Team Foundation Server use Subversion directly for any source code related activity that it needs to report on or otherwise display in its interface?

Similarly, is there any way to make it use Jenkins for its continuous builds?

I have seen various articles that describe how to go "the other way"—i.e. to have Jenkins query a TFS source repository, but that's not what I'd like to do.

Answer (score 4):

No, TFS uses its own proprietary version control and build systems. It doesn't allow other systems like Subversion and Jenkins to be "plugged-in" on the backend. What is the overall scenario you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to use TFS work items with these other services?

*EDIT*

As pointed out below, it probably is worth mentioning that you can have Jenkins build TFS sources but that is more like plugging TFS into Jenkins.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, basically.  I had read http://igorshare.wordpress.com/2010/12/26/can-tfs-be-useful-if-the-sources-are-in-subversion-svn-or-how-to-run-integration-and-nightly-builds-on-tfs-from-svn/ and from there thought that perhaps there was a path toward what I wanted to do.  Basically I have sources in SVN and builds on Jenkins and for various reasons must continue to use those products.  I however have some political and other requirements that say that VSTS must be used for management purposes.  I'd like to tie the two together.

Comment: you can use Jenkins with TFS although it's more like plugging TFS in to Jenkins [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7968849/568475) but you cannot substitute the source control system.